# Error page image missing on meta.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

The following image does not exist:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/img/error-meta-error.png
```

You can see its non-existence here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?error=error&error

Comment: Yep. Compare https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?error=error&error

Comment: Firefox says that "*The image "[https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/img/error-meta-error.png](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/img/error-meta-error.png)" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.*" That's getting a bit too meta(-error) for me...

Answer (score 4):

OOOOOOOOooooooooooppppssss

It should be fixed up now.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?error=error&error